# Why is requirejs trying to load .map?

Tags: requirejs, cdn

I am trying to load scripts from a CDN (cdnjs to be specific), and in requirejs you have to leave the extension off like so:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/static/js/',
    paths: {
        underscore: ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min']
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

But when I do this, the browser tries to load `underscore-min.map` and not `underscore-min.js`.

How do I fix this, and also what is a `.map`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.map` files are needed for [sourceMap](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) support in the browser. This is the last line from the file you load from the CDN:

```
 //# sourceMappingURL=underscore-min.map
```

This line makes your browser to load the `.map` file.

Comment: You can read about this feature [here](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/all-you-need-to-know-about-jquery-source-maps.html). And there you'll also find out how to deactivate the feature from your browser settings.

Comment: Note that this only happens in Chrome.  You can turn this feature off by going to the dev tools settings and un-checking "Enable source maps".