# RequireJS adding '.map' to javascripts rather than '.js' suddenly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js, requirejs

I had this working perfectly fine until just today when suddenly all of my js files being loaded via requirejs cannot be found and its because requirejs decided to give each a '.map' file extension rather than the '.js'

I added the '.js' to the paths just to see and then requirejs still failed because it pointed to 'jquery.min.js.js'

I'm baffled how this would suddenly change for no reason at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
require.config
  baseUrl: 'javascripts'
  paths:
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min'
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore.min'
    backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min'
  shim:
    underscore:
      exports: '_'
    backbone:
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"]
      exports: "Backbone"

require [
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'#,
 ], ($, _, Backbone) ->
   $('body').prepend "<div class='marking-up-header'></div>"
```

Again this was working just fine the last time I worked on this and coming back to it today it was screwed up.[image]

Ok, so I took out require.js altogether and now I'm getting the same missing errors with the '.map' still.  I opened it up in safari (I was using chrome) and I'm not getting these errors at all. Is Chrome having a stroke? does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898165/why-is-requirejs-trying-to-load-map

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @alexanderb noted, this is happening because of the recent support for source maps in Chrome.  To prevent this from happening (if you are not interested in using source maps for minified files), go to the Dev Tools settings panel and uncheck "Enable source maps" under the "Sources" section.  Note however, that this turns off source-map functionality for all minified files that have specified a source map using `// @ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map`.  No need to edit any files.

Comment: This was the issue for me.  I removed the '@' symbol in each of the minified files and it worked again. alexanderb, I tried your solution and was still getting the errors and it makes since considering this line in each of the files.

Does anyone know why this breaks and a real way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

That's probably happening because of your referring minified files.

Typically you always use un-compressed sources, then you optimise the code with `r.js` during deployment, so all referred libraries are got minified anyway.

Try to change from the `path` section and see if issue still appears.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me out bigtime there. Seems like requirejs is indeed adding `.map` extension instead of `.js` if your filename ends with `.min`. No clue why though...

Comment: Okay so, I did some more test with this. And the thing is, requirejs does load the files correctly. However each minified file contained a line like this `// @ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map`. This causes chrome dev tools (or any other debugging tool) to lookup that file so it can supply detailed info when debugging minified files.

Comment: @Hless Thanks, that was exactly my problem. Removed those comments and now no more errors in Chrome console.