# Require.js is appending .map extension to my libraries

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

If I specify my paths config as a remote url they load fine.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',
    underscore: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min',
    backbone: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min',
    mustache: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.min'
  }
})
```

If I move them to local files like this:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery-min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore-min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone-min',
    mustache: 'libs/mustache-min'
  }
})
```

Then it tries to load them as `libs/jquery-min.map`. I can't seem to figure out why it would be appending a `.map` extension. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is requirejs trying to load .map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898165/why-is-requirejs-trying-to-load-map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not require, but your browser:

1. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/
2. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps